# How do I find who created a GCE VM instance in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

**Background**

In our current Google Cloud Project it seems it's common that people create a VM, start it, do some of their stuff and then just leave it there without turning it off or deleting the VM.

I'm trying to write an automated script that pulls the list of VM instances every day and send an E-mail to the VM owners and see if they forgot to turn off their VMs.

**Question**

So is there an easy way to find out who created a GCE VM instance using Google Cloud API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the information in Stackdriver -> Logging -> Logs. The log is a JSON file, the actor field is what you are looking for. You can export the logs for analysis.

See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/

Comment: And what does mean ```user: system``` ?